# How can I get all the data in a row using php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I followed this youtube video tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/C--mu07uhQw). It taught me how to get and post the username to the `index.php` page. I wanted to know how to get all the data in the row not just the `username` (note: I used the `email_address` as the username). The table has `firstname, lastname, email_address, password`

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = md5($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: dashboard.php');
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get all the info from a row?

Comment: @suvojit_007 yes

Comment: By using `*` , you are selecting everything from a row

Comment: @suvojit_007 yes but I don't know how to call each one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.net about `mysqli_query`

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You still need to fetch the result as an associative array to use it (using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for example). The array will have the column names as keys and the column value as value.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    // fetch the result as an associative array here
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery) == 1) {
       // if you are using the email_address as username
       $_SESSION['email_address'] = $result['email_address'];
       $_SESSION['first_name'] = $result['firstname'];
       $_SESSION['last_name'] = $result['lastname'];

       $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
       header('location: dashboard.php');
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password");
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually u didn't get the username from your query but from your POST. You stored the query result into `$result` variable, you may then access the rows with it.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$username' AND password='$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $row['username'];

        //here goes other rows from your DB
        //$row['email'];
        //$row['other_rows'];

        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: dashboard.php');
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use `$result['username']` of `$result['email_address']` it will show Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\revaworks\server.php on line 26

Comment: ah sorry to access object u need to use `->` instead of `[]`. So `$result->username`

Comment: Sorry again, please see edit. You need to fetch the rows of the result. Then from that, you can access the columns

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You are already selecting all the columns from the database so you just need to use it.

The `LIMIT 1`  makes sure you only get one row back and you should not get back more than one row anyways.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {

     $password = md5($password);
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";

     $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
         $_SESSION['email_address'] = $result['username'];
         $_SESSION['firstname'] = $result['firstname'];
         $_SESSION['lastname'] = $result['lastname'];        
         $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: dashboard.php');
     } else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password");
     }
}
```